# completion handler with parameters (Swift)

Tags: swift, scenekit

How do I implement a completion handler that calls a function that takes parameters?

```
myNode.runAction(SCNAction.moveByX(0, y: 40, z: 0, duration: 1), completionHandler: foo(param))
```

Comment: What does the handler need to do?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already?

Comment: I'm trying to limit the scope on my variables, and the function (foo) called at the end of the animation (SCNAction) uses a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way to write it is with a closure:

```
myNode.runAction(SCNAction.moveByX(0, y: 40, z: 0, duration: 1), completionHandler:{param in /* What ever you need to do*/})
```